# Using OpenGL with a headless Tesla K20X for offscreen rendering on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, nvidia, tesla

For Windows, I have to use nvidia-smi to switch to WDDM mode, which negatively affects performance for compute but allows you to use OpenGL. Unfortunately this does not work on Linux and gives me an error that it is unsupported for this platform when running the command on Linux. So far I cannot seem to find any method to enable this on Linux.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming. For general computing questions, you should ask the community at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @ugo, I can understand that in a way but really it is to get my code running on the target hardware which might include changes to my codebase. Also I am not sure it is an issue an admin would run across(though I may be wrong) as you wouldn't run accross it unless you are a developing writing OpenGL code

Comment: @Ugo: This seems pretty on-topic to me. It is domain specific and related to development. There is no code, but that does not matter because the question is about a tool necessary to setup a development environment for a particular specialized piece of hardware.

Comment: @user3629608 good point on people not running into this problem unless writing OpenGL code.